# Adding a yield to a non-suspending function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to build an interruptible version of CharSequence. Something along these lines:

```
  class InterruptableCharSequence(private val delegate: CharSequence) : CharSequence {

  override fun get(index: Int): Char = runBlocking {

      yield() // Suspend here, in case we have cancelled
      delegate[index]
  }

  override fun subSequence(start: Int, end: Int): CharSequence {
      return delegate.subSequence(start, end)
  }

  override fun toString(): String {
      return delegate.toString()
  }
}
```

Since this is implementing an existing interface I can't make `get` a suspending function, but I'd like to call it from a co-routine (several layers up) and be able to interrupt/cancel it. How would I go about making this possible? Is there any way to do so without blocking like this or creating a new coroutine for each Char?

Comment: The only thing you can possibly do is signal the calling coroutine to suspend itself once it gets the control back. For example you can throw a specialized exception. There is no way you'll get your non-suspending function to resume after `yield()` (or whatever equivalent you try to substitute for it).

Comment: Do you really need the `CharSequence` interface? It kinda looks like you want a `Flow<Char>` or `Channel<Char>`, unless you need random access.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make interruptible Regexes and Regex takes a CharSequence.